# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - La página dominio.com te ha redirigido demasiadas veces

Tags: login, redirección, symfony5

Tengo una pequeña aplicación hecha en Symfony 5, al intnetar acceder a la zona de usuario (que es todo, excepto la página de login) me aparece el error que he mencionado en el título.

He probado todo lo que se me ha ido ocurriendo: revisar el .htaccess, el controlador, el security.yaml...

Si accedo con usuario ROLE_ADMIN, no me da ningún problema, pero su accedo con cualquier otro usuario, se me queda en la redirección infinita y no hay manera de que funcione.

Este es el security.yaml:

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_EDITOR: [ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER


    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            # target: app_any_route

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/reservar, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/usuario, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Este es el SecurityController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\SignUpRepository;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController {

/**
* @Route("/login", name="app_login")
*/
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, UserRepository $repo, SignUpRepository $repo2):Response {
 $registro = $repo2->find(1);
 // if ($this->getUser()) {
 //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
 // }

 // get the login error if there is one
 $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
 // last username entered by the user
 $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

if ($lastUsername != NULL) {
  $currentUser = new User();

  $lst = $repo->findAll();

  foreach ($lst as $user) {
    if ($user->getUserIdentifier() == $user) {//Si está como registro en la base de datos
      if ($user->getUserIdentifier() == $lastUsername) {
        $currentUser = $user;
      }
    }
  }
  $id = $currentUser->getId();
  //En la entidad User el método getRoles() no debe meter al array el rol de usuario
  if ($currentUser->getRoles()[0] == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('admon_reservas');
  }
  else {//Si tiene rol usuario va a la principal
    if ($currentUser->getRoles()[0] == 'ROLE_USER') {
      return $this->redirectToRoute('reservar');
    }
    else {//Si no entra porque no existe el usuario o no tiene rol
      //return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
      $this->addFlash('danger', 'Datos de acceso incorrectos.');
      return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error, 'registro' => $registro]);
    }
  }
}
 return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error, 'registro' => $registro]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
 */
public function logout() {
throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
   }
}
```

Y este es el .htaccess

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
#<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
#    Options -MultiViews
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
# (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
# rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
# endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
# redirect -> request -> ...).
# So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
# to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
# environment variable, you have 2 choices:
# - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
# - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
#   following RewriteCond (best solution)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
  RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
    # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
    # and the generated links can still be used.
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
</IfModule>
```

También he probado a cambiar directamente en BBDD los roles y nada.